# Is it possible to register a client as "dev team" or "sub-dev" visible in byline on App Store?

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, google-play

More generally:

A strategy to display the client company name in App Store and Google Play/Android Market.

At the base of this question is the need felt by the company who paid for the development of the app to have their company seen as the originator of the app. It's not enough to have it as a search word or mentioned in the description, they want it in the byline.

I guess most of you know of the problem, and it's strange because the straight-forward solution is both obvious and causes a lot of problems: multiple accounts.

Our client is happy to pay for a separate Apple Developer account, but with this follows the inevitably setting up of separate Apple IDs, downloadable certificates, making the same XCode installation like the multiple setups, and on and on and on... if someone has managed to think out a process for making this easy and seamless and think that multiple accounts really are straight-forward, I would like to learn that process. Any multiple accounts will be registered by, developed for, and managed by us for the client.

On Market the process might be much easier, so for that I'd like to just survey for gotchas, if you have any. Just register another account and upload any .apk with the correct reverse-domain id and go?

If you have arguments that you have used to talk a client out of multiple accounts, I'd like to know them. Also, techniques to strengthen their branding in the app or on App Store so they will unambiguously link the client's company name to the app and not the developers.

Basically, I'm just trying to find inroads to headache-avoidal.

Comment: good question but not related to programming... maybe more suited for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sure, fine. Moderators are welcome to move it to where it should be. Even though I've seen similar questions on here, I was hesitant. But that's fine :)

Comment: @lukya disagree. The `android-market` tag exists here for a reason.

Comment: @Henrik Erlandsson Read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Comment: @MisterSmith yes, that's the manual. I'm still confident I will be able to publish a new app to a new client's account without Eclipse giving me hassle. So I think potential gotchas will be on the XCode side of things and hope someone who has published in a client's name has some feedback for me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a company then you can register with only their name in app store. As I remembered, they required us to fax our company's business registration and other tax information to them and that will show on the page in app store as the seller. As I understand, they don't want you to mass up with the name even through that's related to the company.

Comment: In other words, no, Apple wants you to get a separate dev account, with all the certificate goodness that entails. Another way to say it is that they didn't think any company would want to develop for business clients who want *their* name under the icon in App Store. They could have solved it by splitting up bylines into "publisher" and "developer", and they still can. But since they haven't done so in 18 months I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: I think it is typical Apple way of doing things. They don't like giving people options.